# Android: cannot cast LifeCycleOwner to an activity error in CamerX preview code

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am trying to show a preview of the camera on a textureView using camera API...
There are barely any tutorials relating to cameraX api in java so it is really hard understanding how the API works...The code gives me a runtime exception which states that

> "Activity cannot be cast to lifeCycleowner"

```
PreviewConfig config = new PreviewConfig.Builder().build();
Preview preview = new Preview(config);

preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
    new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput previewOutput) {

            textureView.setSurfaceTexture(previewOutput.getSurfaceTexture());

        };
});

CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, preview);
```

Comment: `this` needs to inherit from `FragmentActivity`, such as by extending `AppCompatActivity`. If you have just a plain `Activity` here, that will not work.

Comment: Do you mean `cannot cast activity to LifeCycleOwner` rather than the other opposite?

Comment: Please add full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code i posted is working fine now i made the mistake of implementing it in an activity. It had to be implemented in a fragment :|

Answer (score 0):

create your custom lifecycle

```
   //lifecycle for camera
        CustomLifecycle lifecycle=new CustomLifecycle();
        lifecycle.doOnResume();
        lifecycle.doOnStart();
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(lifecycle, preview,imageCapture);


    public class CustomLifecycle implements LifecycleOwner {

        private LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;
         CustomLifecycle() {
            mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
            mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
        }

        void doOnResume() {
            mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
        }

        void doOnStart() {
            mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
        }

        @NonNull
        public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
            return mLifecycleRegistry;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already suggested in official codelab of camerax that you have to update appcompat dependency:

> If Android Studio complains about "this" being not a LifecycleOwner, try rebuilding the project or updating the appcompat dependency to version 1.1.0 or higher.

Check on below link:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#5